# Where is that city?

Tags: diablo-iii

I was browsing the [Wallpapers sections of the Diablo 3 website](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/media/wallpapers/?keywords=&view#/wallpaper015) and found this image.

[image: An island city built around an harbor; a Diablo 3 logo at the bottom]

I can't remember such a city in the game, so where is this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the Skovos Isles, one of the two Amazonian isles - it wasn't included in Diablo III, but the art was done as part of their actions to flesh out and clean up the lore surrounding the Diablo series.

> Bashiok: It is Skovos, and I think this piece was something that Leonard showed and discussed at the WWI Lore and Environment Art panel.
>
> It isn't a location that you'll visit in Diablo III, but the artwork is a good example of the work and thought going in to fleshing out the world of Sanctuary. It's already a very complex world with a lot of locations and events, but a lot of it still isn't visually or contextually realized. As we want to create the feeling of a world outside of your immediate view it's important to create or expand upon the locations and stories of that world.
>
> As we're working to create Diablo III we're also working to create a more visually complete Sanctuary.